# Error Deploying Java 8 Jars(EJB) With Lambdas - glassfish server 4.1

Tags: java, lambda, ejb, java-8, glassfish-4

When deploying an EJB jar using the compatability=v2 flag, and that jar contains another JAR which has a class that uses Java 8 lambda expressions, the deployment fails and I get the following errors in the log:

use annotations (@Stateless)

```
Failed to scan for annotations: 52264
Archive type of (path to EJB JAR) was not recognized.
```

Checked also change the order of the files, leaving the class that has lambda lastly the deployment works correctly.

I use netbeans IDE in the last version

glassfish too is up to date

I'm out of ideas for this.

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish bug: [GLASSFISH-21287](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21287)

> Error Deploying Java 8 Jars With Lambdas Using compatibility=v2